# Particular Integrals [Trig]

Tags: integration

For particular integrals such as

$$ x'' - x=2\cos(t)$$

We need to guess that $x_p=a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)$

however for an integral such as

$$ x'' + x=3\cos(t)$$

We need to guess that $x_p=t(a\cos(t)+b\sin(t))$

These integrals are pretty similar but one of them has their particular integral with a $t$ and the other one does not. How can you tell from looking at the integral which one to guess?

Comment: Using Undetermined Coefficients, the roots of the homogeneous equation in the second one are $\pm ~ i$, which implies cosine and sine terms as the solution. Given that the DEQ solution already has a cosine term, we need to multiply our guess of a particular solution, $x_p = a \cos t + b \sin t$, by $t$. You can find a nice tutorial at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx. For the first one, the roots of the homogeneous are $\pm~ 1$, which implies a solution $x_h = c_1e^{-t} + b e^t$ and the ODE solution does not contain that. Clear?

Comment: @Moo Yes that is clear! Thank you. If this was an answer I would have accepted. :)